# Get data from table in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have table with name `f_t_tik` (**has no 's' in the end of its name**). Can I get data from this table from Rails? With my knowlegde, I know when I write code like `@data = FTTik.all` I received the SQL query like `SELECT * from f_t_tiks;`. But I must not change the name of table from `f_t_tik` to `f_t_tiks`. Is there a solution to resolve my problem?

Comment: Do you have a model for this?  What is it called?

Comment: @RockwellRice this model's name is FTTik, but I can rename the Model. I want, by any way, I can get data from table f_t_tik, not f_t_tiks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can specify the name of a models table in the model.rb file in  your case you would need to add:

```
self.table_name = "f_t_tik"
```

to the file models/f_t_tik.rb